# Python: ¿Cómo actualizar pip?

Tags: python, windows, pip

Quiero actualizar mi pip de Python la versión más reciente. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el comando que debo de introducir en el cmd de windows?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisaste este post de stackoverflow en ingles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment

Comment: @Cig: Se me pasó, ahora lo he leído. Edita una respuesta para que te la pueda validar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para actualizar `pip` se usa `pip`. No especificas que versión de Python estás usando, pero si es la versión **Python 3** la mejor manera es la siguiente:

```
c:\ruta\a\python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Si usas Python 2 y está en tu ruta de búsqueda, solo escribe

```
c:\> pip install --upgrade pip
```

Si agregas a tu pregunta que versión usas, recibirás mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que ingresar el comando

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

con eso te debería de actualizar **pip** sin problemas

Answer (score 3):

En python 3 y windows es insertar en cmd:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```