# Error al importar módulo instalado correctamente con pip con Atom-python-run

Tags: python, numpy, atom-editor

El problema que tengo es que hace muy poco he empezado a programar Python 3, nunca he estudiado programación y todo lo aprendo por de internet, he jugado con arduino y me parecía hora de probar otro lenguaje, pero a la hora de añadir una librería o modulo, me da un error, he buscado mucho y parece ser que a mucha gente le pasaba pero lo solucionaron instalando la librería con PIP, PIP3 o usando una versión adecuada, lo he probado todo y aun así no me funciona, uso Python 3.7, voy aponer un código de los que he probado:

```
import numpy

data=[86,87,88,86,87,85,86] # La deviacion de estos sera de 0.9

x=numpy.std(data) # std saca la desviacion
print(x)
```

Es un código de prueba, y siempre me reporta este error cuando le doy a arrancar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "I:\programaci¾n\Python\01 desviacion standard.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy

Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 0.046 s
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Uso el editor de código Atom con el paquete `Atom-python-run` otros códigos de Python sin librerías me funcionan adecuadamente.

Por otro lado, tengo problemas con el Atom, ya que cada día tengo que desinstalar y reinstalar el paquete `Atom-python-run` ya que si no me reporta:

> internal/validators.js:125

Para ser mas exactos lo que he probado ha sido, instalar con pip (`pip install numpy`) y lo mismo con pip3 después de desinstalarlo, instalar versiones especificas de la librería, básicamente buscaba el error y todo lo que me salia lo probaba, hasta que me he quedado sin cosas que probar...

Claramente esto no me pasa solo con NumPy, me pasa con todas las librerías.

---

### Respondiendo a los comentarios

Si ejecuto `import sys;print(sys.executable)` obtengo:

> ```
> C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe
> ```

En cuanto a `pip -V`:

> ```
> $ pip -V
> pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\inder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip(python 3.7) 
>
> $pip3 -V
> pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\inder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip(python 3.7)
> ```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. En un script en Atom pon lo siguiente: `import sys;print(sys.executable)` y muestra que te imprime. Por otro lado, en una terminal del sistema muestra la salida de `pip -V`  y `pip3 -V`. Es prácticamente seguro que estás instalando en el intérprete incorrecto si la instalación fue correcta, sin excepciones al instalar o compilar.

Comment: Dices que has probado todo para instalar `numpy` y que no te funciona. ¿Qué es lo que has probado y qué error te da? Si no lo has hecho, sigue las instrucciones de la documentación y dinos en dónde te atascas: <https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#installing-numpy>

Comment: Voy a añadir una respuesta ya que si no no me cabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema bastante frecuente a pesar de ser bastante simple. pip siempre está enlazado a un intérprete Python concreto y es en él y solo en él en el que instalará los paquetes. En tu caso vemos (gracias a `pip -V`) que tanto `pip` como `pip3` apunta al intérprete instalado en la ruta:

```
C:\Users\inder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37
```

En cambio Atom está usando como intérprete (gracias a `import sys;print(sys.executable)`) lo que a todas luces es un entorno virtual en la ruta:

```
C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv
```

Para instlar en el intérprete que usa Atom tienes dos opciones:

### Activar el entorno virtual y usar pip normalmente

En una terminal/CMD introduces lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

si todo va bien debes observar que la dirección indicada en la consola a cambiado, ahora deberías poder hacer:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

o bien directamente:

```
pip install numpy
```

### Usar la ruta directa al intérprete y lanzar pip como módulo

Para mi es la preferida, es explícita y nos aseguramos de estar instalando en el intérprete adecuado si o si:

```
C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

Todas las versiones de Python oficiales (descargadas desde python.org, otra cosa es las de los repositorios oficiales de las distros Linux por ejemplo) llevan instalado `pip` de forma predeterminada siempre.

Comment: He tratado de hacerlo pero pip no me deja usar --user, necesito pip 20.02 y para actualizarlo necesito --user.
No encuentro para descargarlo.


`C:\Users\inder>pip install --upgrade pip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] 
Acceso denegado: 'C:\\Users\\inder\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-an5q9wze\\pip.exe'
Consider using the "--user" option or check the permissions.

 C:\Users\inder>pip install --upgrade pip --user
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\inder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (20.1)`

Comment: No me cabía esto en el anterior, disculpa, ejecutándolo como administrador tampoco me funciona, he probado a buscarlo para descargarlo des instalarlo y reinstalarlo peor no encuentro la versión 20.02
La indo que he obtenido es de aquí:
[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37784/python-c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-pip]

Comment: Al tratar de instalar numpy me devuelve:
`C:\Users\inder>C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy --user
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Y en administrador igual
No obstante tengo la version 20.01 y he probado a reinstalarla, pero nada

Comment: Intenta sin `--user`: `C:\Users\inder>C:\Users\inder\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy`, si te da problemas de permisos intenta en modo administrador o activa el entorno primero.

Comment: Acabo de reinstalar pip
`Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.1`
Y ahora me dice lo mismo
`Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Me estoy saltando algo?
He probado todo en modo admin

Comment: Bien, con lo de activar el entorno virtual primero ha dado resultado, MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS, aunque sigo sin entender por que me dice que tengo pip 18.1 cuando acabo de instalar 20.1...

Comment: Si te fijas en la ruta se actualiza el pip de la instalación del sistema (`c:\users\inder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37`) no el del entorno . De todas si tal como has instalado numpy, con el entorno activado de idéntica forma tratas de actualizarlo todo debería ir bien.

Comment: Si, muchas gracias por todo